# How to make a Pick property Partial

Tags: typescript, typescript-partial

I have this function

```
function someThing(someArg: Pick<HTMLElement, 'id' | 'style'>) {...}
```

However, I only want to add some styles to `someArg.style`, not all the style from `CSSStyleDeclaration`. Otherwise, the input of the function will be huge.

So I expect to have something like `Pick` from `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` not `Pick` from `CSSStyleDeclaration`

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want the Picked properties to be partial if they are object types ? A conditiona type with a mapped type could work well for that `type PartialProps<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object  ? Partial<T[P]> : T[P]
}` and use it `PartialProps< Pick<HTMLElement, 'id' | 'style'>>`

Comment: Does not `Pick<Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>, 'color'>` work just fine for what you want?

Comment: Really good approach @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your type is more complicated than just `Pick`ing some properties from an existing type, you might want to spell it out in its own interface:

```
interface SomeArg {
  id: HTMLElement['id'],
  style: Partial<HTMLElement['style']>
}

function someThing(someArg: SomeArg) { }

someThing({id: "id", style: {
  zIndex: "1"
}})
```

I'm using [lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) to make it clear that the `id` and `style` properties are related to those from `HTMLElement`, but you could use just `string` and `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` instead.

If you really need to use something like `Pick` that allows subproperties to be `Partial` you can make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to do it, but I can't tell from your question if you need something programmatic.

#### UPDATE

I guess you do want it to be programmatic (although for just two properties I wouldn't bother, myself) so here's a way to define `PickPartial` so that you are picking from `Partial` properties instead of the properties themselves.  I assume you don't need it to be recursive (you don't need each of the subproperties to themselves be `Partial`):

```
type PickPartial<T, K extends keyof T> = {[P in K]: Partial<T[P]>};

function someThing(someArg: PickPartial<HTMLElement, 'id'|'style'>) { }
someThing({id: "1", style: {
  zIndex: "1"
}})
```

Note that while this technically makes `id` the type `Partial<string>`, that is fine because mapped types do not modify primitives.. `Partial<string>` is just `string`.  So the type of `someArg` is the same as the `SomeArg` interface I spelled out above.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is a correct way to implement it but I prefer to not repeat the ```id``` or ```style``` keys. I would choose the solution from @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - create a new type ```PartialProps<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? Partial<T[P]> : T[P] }```

Comment: If you want to add that version to your answer I don't mind, I don't plan of adding an answer

Comment: You don't even need to distinguish `object` types because mapped types don't modify primitives (e.g., `Partial<string>` is just `string`).  I guess I'll add it to this answer.

Comment: @jcalz hm missed that, guess it was more recent work I'm not sure about primitives but I am pretty sure `Partial` used to mangle array types ..

Comment: Yeah it used to mangle array types (not that an array is a primitive) but now maps them quite nicely.

Comment: Just can't be better :D